# Rendering fluid simulation in false colors

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I need to render a fluid simulation in digital style like in the picture below. I prefer eevee for rendering but if someone know how to get it in cycles this also might help. So literally I need particles with coloros like in the picture in final render but not with water shader.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my guess is that he wants these colors blue - red that are used for velocity of water to be visible in final render, @roflvite, personally I think that you should just remove all unnecessary gizmos and render your viewport or even screenshot it... is that not good enough for you use?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann. Thanks, that works

Answer (score 1):

To render particles like in the example you could either disable *Overlays* in the *3D Viewport* and render from there with *View* > *Viewport Render Animation* as mentioned in the comments, this would also render very quickly.

Note that the other way described below **only** works in *Cycles*, since the *Particle Info* node in the material cannot be used in *Eevee*:

If you want "real" particles with maybe shadows, glossy surfaces or whatever, you can give the domain a simple *Transparent BSDF* set to full white to make it invisible for the render and to make particles inside it visible.

First of all, create an object you want to use as particle. The best will be object with very few geometry since there will be lots of them, so maybe a cube or an icosphere with a resolution of 1. But of course that's also dependent on your PC's power.

Then you go to the *Particle Properties* of the domain and select the particle system called **Liquid**. Under *Render*, change the *Render As* option from "Halo" to "Object" and choose an *Instance Object*, e.g. an icosphere you have created. Set the *Scale* to your liking.

[image: particle settings]

The material on the particle object now needs a *Particle Info* node. There you have a *Velocity* output. I plugged it into a *Vector Math* node set to *Length* to calculate the overall length of the velocity vectors, i.e. how long ("fast") they are no matter in which direction. Of course you can do anything else like using *Separate XYZ* or whatever. Then I adjusted the result with a *Map Range* node and colored it with a *Color Ramp*. These steps are of course optional and depend on what you want to achieve.

[image: particle material]

The result could look like this (sorry for the bad GIF quality):

[image: colored particles]